# Creating symbol table for gdb using cmake

Tags: cmake, debug-symbols

Is there any way to create only symbol table using cmake for gdb ?

Answer (score -12, accepted):

The usual way to produce debugging information for `gdb` is to pass `-g` to the `gcc` or `g++` compiler (and also at linking time).

Look into the [Cmake FAQ](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_FAQ) for how to get a debuggable executable.

Comment: I want only symbol  table is it possible ?

Comment: It probably is possible, but it is not a `cmake` specific question. I think that they are some Linux utilities (perhaps binutils related) to extract debugging information from an ELF executable, but I never used them. http://www.moythreads.com/wordpress/2009/08/31/debugging-information-in-separate-files/

Comment: When folks ask a question it is rare that they wanted to be pointed to a manual. Thanks but no thanks....

Comment: it IS a cmake question. With gcc or clang, when profiling, you generally enable both symbols and optimization (-g -O2). Whereas with clang you have optimization enabled in release mode, and symbols in debug mode.

Answer (score 156):

Add this line to the file ***CMakeLists.txt***:

```
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug)
```

Comment: This also disables optimization. For profiling instead of debugging, you generally want both optimization and symbols (aka -g O2). How to do this with clang?

Comment: I added this flag to my cmake file however I dont see any difference in the size of the binary which is usually increased after adding `-g` which flag for adding debug symbols.

Answer (score 129):

Compile in Release mode optimized but adding debug symbols, useful for profiling:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo ...
```

or compile with NO optimization and adding debug symbols:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug ...
```

Comment: Note that RelWithDebInfo is great, but also changes the optimization from -O3 to -O2 due to historic reasons: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/merge_requests/591

Answer (score 0):

If you need the debug symbols for profiling then paste this into `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE RelWithDebInfo)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using QtCreator, **remove** (or comment out) any line containing `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE`:

```
# set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug) 
# set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release) <- comment out such lines
```

Reason: if you explicitly set CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE in your CmakeLists.txt, QtCreator will *not* allow you to set any other target.